# Adding ChartTitle in excel XP VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a title to my chart using this code:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 3").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "EXAMPLE"
```

In Excel 2010, 2013.... it works fine but when i run in XP crash saying: Can't obtain the Characters property of ChartTitle class

What's im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: by XP are you referring to Windows XP or Excel 2003/XP?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, Excel XP

Comment: My guess is that the method for changing the chart title changed.  I'd recommend recording a macro in XP of you changing the title and see what it uses

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working and can't find documentation on XP. However, you can just use

ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text

property to set the title according to documentation. I don't have a way of testing it in XP but it might work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195126.aspx